# Perl: Regex - matching values with alphabets

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I have written a small perl "hack" to replace 1's with alphabets in a range of columns in a tab delimited file. The file looks like this:

```
Chr Start   End Name    Score   Strand  Donor   Acceptor    Merged_Transcript   Gencode Colon   Heart   Kidney  Liver   Lung    Stomach
chr10   100177483   100177931   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0
chr10   100178014   100179801   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
chr10   100179915   100182125   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
chr10   100182270   100183359   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
chr10   100183644   100184069   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
```

The gola is to take columns 11 through 16 and append letters A to Z if a value of 1 is seen in those columns. My code so far is producing an empty output and this is my first time doing regular expressions.

```
cat infile.txt \
| perl -ne '@alphabet=("A".."Z");
            $is_known_intron = 0;
            $is_known_donor = 1;
            $is_known_acceptor = 1;
            chomp;
            $_ =~ s/^\s+//;
            @d = split /\s+/, $_;
            @d_bool=@d[$11-$16];
            $ct=1;
            $known_intron = $d[$10];
            $num_of_overlapping_gene = $d[$9];
            $known_acceptor = $d[$8];
            $known_donor = $d[$7];
            $k="";
            if (($known_intron == $is_known_intron) and ($known_donor == $is_known_donor) and ($known_acceptor == $is_known_acceptor)) {
               for ($i = 0; $i < scalar @d_bool; $i++){
                   $k.=$alphabet[$i] if ($d_bool[$i])
                }
                $alphabet_ct{$k}+=$ct;
            }
            END
            {
               foreach $k (sort keys %alphabet_ct){
                   print join("\t", $k, $alphabet_ct{$k}), "\n";
               }
            } '\
   > Outfile.txt
```

What should I be doing instead?

Thanks!

*** Edit ***

Expected Output

```
ABCD 45
BCD 23
ABCDEF 1215
```

so on and so forth.

Comment: Have you tried putting debugging statements in your code so you can see what it's doing at each step?

Comment: There are numerous problems with your code -- to start with, you should add `use strict; use warnings;` to the head of the script to give you clues as to what's going wrong. Do you know that arrays are 0-indexed in perl? And that all the references to `$7`, `$8`, `$9`, etc., are not returning any values?

Comment: Does the expected output you've posted correspond with the input? Also, any formatting it had has been lost -- you need to indent it or line breaks and spacing get removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted your code into a script for ease of debugging. I've put comments in the code to point out dodgy bits:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %alphabet_ct;
my @alphabet = ( "A" .. "Z" );

my $is_known_intron   = 0;
my $is_known_donor    = 1;
my $is_known_acceptor = 1;

while (<DATA>) {
    # don't process the first line
    next unless /chr10/;
    chomp;
    # this should remove whitespace at the beginning of the line but is doing nothing as there is none
    $_ =~ s/^\s+//;

    my @d = split /\s+/, $_;
    # the range operator in perl is .. (not "-")
    my @d_bool         = @d[ 10 .. 15 ];
    my $known_intron   = $d[9];
    my $known_acceptor = $d[7];
    my $known_donor    = $d[6];
    my $k              = "";
    # this expression is false for all the data in the sample you provided as
    # $is_known_intron is set to 0
    if (    ( $known_intron   == $is_known_intron )
        and ( $known_donor    == $is_known_donor )
        and ( $known_acceptor == $is_known_acceptor ) )
    {
        for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @d_bool; $i++ ) {
            $k .= $alphabet[$i] if $d_bool[$i];
        }
        # it is more idiomatic to write $alphabet_ct{$k}++;
        # $alphabet_ct{$k} += $ct;
        $alphabet_ct{$k}++;
    }
}
foreach my $k ( sort keys %alphabet_ct ) {
    print join( "\t", $k, $alphabet_ct{$k} ) . "\n";
}

__DATA__
Chr Start   End Name    Score   Strand  Donor   Acceptor    Merged_Transcript   Gencode Colon   Heart   Kidney  Liver   Lung    Stomach
chr10   100177483   100177931   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0
chr10   100178014   100179801   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
chr10   100179915   100182125   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
chr10   100182270   100183359   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
chr10   100183644   100184069   .   .   -   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
```

With `$is_known_intron` set to 1, the sample data gives the results:

```
ABCDE   1
ABCE    1
ACD 1
CE  2
```